# How to verify date format using regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

How to verify below format using regular expression in c#.. can you help me..

```
Today's Date: 03:30 AM ET, 02/15/2013
```

I used below format but its not working..

```
@"^ Today's Date: (\d{2})(\:)(\d{2})$ AM ET, ^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$"
```

Comment: C# or Java? Which one? And will your date always be in this format? How about `PM`?

Comment: in C# ..ya i want to verify date also..

Comment: why don't you go for DateTime.TryParse() instead..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are 3 problems with your regular expression:

- There is a leading space between `^` and `T` of *Today's*
- the portions of your regular expression for matching the day and the month are in the wrong order
- The `$` and `^` midway through the expression shouldn't be there

`(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` matches 01 to 31
and `(0[1-9]|1[012])` matches 01 to 12

making the corrected pattern:

```
^Today's Date: (\d{2})(\:)(\d{2}) AM ET, (0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$
```

But as [Rahul R.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1421196/rahul-r) says in the comments, using a proper date parsing method is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
^Today's Date: ([01][0-9]|[2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]) [AP]M ET, ((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(?=(0[13578]|1[02]))(0[13578]|1[02])|(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)/(?=(0[469]|11))(0[469]|11)|(0[1-9]|[12][0-9])/(?=(02))(02))/(0{3}[1-9]|((?!0{3}\d)\d{4}))$
```

Comment: The below code is working fine for me ,@"^Today's Date: (\d{2})(\:)(\d{2}) [AP]M ET, (\d{2})(\/)(\d{2})(\/)(\d{4})$" thanks for help....

Comment: @saran but it allows 99:99 AM ET, 33/44/5555